# why isnt ajax pagination working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I have tried to implement pagination that is loaded via ajax. I followed [this](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commits/ajax) tutorial in a blank project and it worked. However I have tried to implement it in a current project and it just isnt working. I can toggle through the pagination but the image should be changing and it isnt.

here is the view

```
%tbody#entries
  = render @photos

#image_paginator
  = paginate @photos, :remote => true
```

the controller (EntriesController) action

```
  def index
    @photos = Photo.with_approved_state.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#entries').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@photos) %>');
$('#image_paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@photos, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

_photo partial

```
%td.post
    = link_to (image_tag photo.attachment.url), entry_path(photo)
```

If you need any info just ask. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

after much messing around I suddenly realised the error in my ways.

The code above is fine apart from you can't have a tbody without being in a table, which is what I had.

```
%table
  %tbody#entries
    = render entries
```

Doing this made the hole darn thing work!